# Make a pause in the Sheets script, sleep not working

Tags: google-sheets, time, copy, sleep, pause

I have a script where I want it to pause for about 1 minute, before continuing. Right now with the sleep() function all I get is that the script wait until making all the action instead of pausing before continuing. Here is my script :

`````
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("").getRange('B1').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById("").getRange('B1').getValue() + 1);

  Utilities.sleep(60000);
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OVERVIEW");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("").getSheetByName("RAWDATADUPS");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow();
  targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);

  var sourceSheet20 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OVERVIEW20MIN");
  var sourceData20 = sourceSheet20.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetSS20 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("").getSheetByName("RAWDATA20DUP");
  var targetRangeTop20 = targetSS20.getLastRow();
  targetSS20.getRange(targetRangeTop20+1,1,sourceData20.length,sourceData20[0].length).setValues(sourceData20);````
`````

Comment: I can quite understand the issue. What is the difference between waiting and pausing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on where the sleep command is, you are just waiting before initializing your variables. Your phrase continue makes me think there must be some loop SOMEWHERE further down. If this is the case then you can just put the sleep command into the loop and it will pause for 1 minute on each iteration.